# How can I make a Visual Studio CListCtrl modifiable like a CEdit by a user from the GUI?

Tags: visual-c++

Not sure how to type in text to a CListCtrl at run-time?
For creation of my CListCtrl(all data is later added from another method):

```
pList = new CListCtrl;
pList->Create(LVS_REPORT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(480, 10, 480+140, 370), this, 1000);
pList->SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES); 

LVCOLUMN lvColumn;

lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvColumn.cx = 60;
lvColumn.pszText = "Iteration";
pList->InsertColumn(0, &lvColumn);

lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_WIDTH;
lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
lvColumn.cx = 80;
lvColumn.pszText = "Value";
pList->InsertColumn(1, &lvColumn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LVS_EDITLABELS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774739.aspx) to make one (but only one) column editable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only by creating your own control subclassing from CListCtrl.

Other suggestion i have is, create a dialog with edit boxes reflecting columns in your CListCtrl. For e.g. If you have 2 columns Name and age, create a dialog with two edit box for name and age respectively. Show the dialog for the user to enter the value and when the user close the dialog get the values and insert it as a row. You can show the dialog when the user double clicks the list control or have a seperate add button.

sameway you can use the same dialog for editing the values in the listcontrol row by row.